# Postgres: data types - How to store uint64 in postresql

Tags: postgresql

Bigint in postgresql is 8 byte integer. which is has half the range as uint64 (as one bit is used to sign the integer)

I need to do a lot of aggregation on the column and I am under the impression that aggregation on NUMERIC type is slow in comparison to integer types.

How should I optimize my storage in this case?

Comment: Are you sure your operation will overflow a signed 64-bit counter? Why do you think it won't overflow an unsigned 64-bit counter?

Comment: I'm still learning postgres, but it sure seems that we should be able to write procedures to to do our operations and if there's a JIT (or other optimizing compiler) involved, it would *ideally* be able to "compile them away", since every CPU supports unsigned integral operations.

Comment: @IvanVoras In my case, I am parsing data from binary packets. The field I'm storing is allocated exactly 8 bytes and is encoded as an unsigned integer. I also know that the field may wrap eventually so I need to be able to store the max value.

Comment: @medley56 if you are using a low-level-ish language like Go or C++ or Rust, you could use the binary string data type, `bytea` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-binarystring.html) and just store binary data as binary data (as long as you don't do computation and aggregation in SQL over this field). Other than that, you could use an unofficial extension such as https://github.com/petere/pguint .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you have a concrete reason, just use `NUMERIC`. It *is* slower, quite a lot slower, but that might not matter as much as you think.

You don't really have any alternative, as PostgreSQL doesn't support unsigned 64-bit integers at the SQL level. You could add a new datatype as an extension module, but it'd be a lot of work.

You could shove the unsigned 64-bit int bitwise into a 64-bit signed int, so values above maxuint64/2 are negative. But that'll be totally broken for aggregation, and would generally be horribly ugly.

Answer (score 3):

`sum()` will return `numeric` if the input is `bigint` so it will not overflow

```
select sum(a)
from (values (9223372036854775807::bigint), (9223372036854775807)) s(a)
;
         sum          
----------------------
 18446744073709551614
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 3):

There is also an extension to provide an additional uint64 datatype in postgresql. See [Github](https://github.com/petere/pguint)

It is by [Peter Eisentraut](http://peter.eisentraut.org/)

Comment: There's also the [varint](https://pgxn.org/dist/varint/www/index.html) extension found on PGXN